# Enqueue and Dequeue back and forward

Tags: vb.net

I made this card game and i chose to loop players turns this way.

```
Private Sub Players()
    c.Enqueue(Player1Name)
    c.Enqueue(Player2Name)
    c.Enqueue(Player3Name)
    c.Enqueue(Player4Name)
End Sub

Private Sub btnNextPlayer_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) btnNextPlayer_Click
    c.Dequeue()
End Sub

Private Sub btnPreviousPlayer_CLick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) btnPreviousPlayer_CLick
    c.??????????????????????
End Sub
```

Now everything works fine over and over when i move to next player with c.Dequeue.

But now let's say i want to go back and forward to the previous and next player within that Players Sub.

Is there any way i could do this WITHOUT messing with the Players sub?

Comment: You understand the a `Queue<>` object it meant to be used to add and remove items first in first out. To transverse the players you either need use `foreach` or use a `List<>` with indexing.

Comment: You really should put your players in a list and then reference them by index. Then you can increment and decrement the index when you need to. The only way to do it the current way is to clear the queue and rebuild it every time you click previous.

Comment: Yea i know how to do it the hard way :p , but i was still hoping :D

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, use a `List<>` to transverse through the players. See example skeleton model below:

```
Public Class Player
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set
            m_Name = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Name As String
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(name As String) As Player
        Return New Player() With { _
            Key .Name = name _
        }
    End Operator
End Class

Class Game
    Private current As Integer
    Private players As List(Of Player)

    Public Sub New()
        players = New List(Of Player)()
        players.Add("Player 1")
        players.Add("Player 2")
        players.Add("Player 3")
        players.Add("Player 4")
        current = -1
    End Sub

    Public Function GetCurrentPlayer() As Player
        Return If(current >= 0 AndAlso current < players.Count, players(current), String.Empty)
    End Function

    Public Sub BeginGame()
        current = 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub NextPlayer()
        ' select next, or wrap around after last player
        current = (current + 1) Mod players.Count
    End Sub

    Public Sub PreviousPlayer()
        ' select previous, or go to end before fist player
        current = (current + players.Count - 1) Mod players.Count
    End Sub


    Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim game As New Game()
        game.BeginGame()
        ' Player 1
        Debug.Print(game.GetCurrentPlayer().Name)
        game.NextPlayer()
        game.NextPlayer()
        game.NextPlayer()
        ' Player 4
        Debug.Print(game.GetCurrentPlayer().Name)
        game.PreviousPlayer()
        ' Player 3
        Debug.Print(game.GetCurrentPlayer().Name)
        game.NextPlayer()
        game.NextPlayer()
        ' Player 1
        Debug.Print(game.GetCurrentPlayer().Name)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I cannot change my Players sub. 

If i do decide to do this i know how to do it and i will have to rewrite like 1k lines of code and few full days of rethinking.

That's why i'm asking u guys. To get a simple solution if there is one :-/

Comment: Sh you _have_ to use a `Queue` object? It is not clear from the question.

Comment: Can you use two `Queue` objects, so when you `Dequeue()` from one you `Enqueue()` to the other? What happens here is your `Dequeue()` removes the `Player` and it gets lost in space unless stored elsewhere. And without further knowledge of your architecture it is impossible to answer this question.

Comment: Yea this could work. 
I have a maximum nr of 6 Players and each round when they get Dequeed i can just store them into something and use them.
How could i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try having two `Queue(Of Player)` objects

```
Private Sub btnNextPlayer_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) btnNextPlayer_Click
    d.Enqueue(c.Dequeue())
End Sub

Private Sub btnPreviousPlayer_CLick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) btnPreviousPlayer_CLick
    c.Enqueue(d.Dequeue())
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer helped. After playing with Queues and Stacks for some hours i could find a solution. I will post it as an answer.